# Disabling command block output in the console

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

I have my own server hosted by server.pro, but because of extensive repeating command block logging, the site crashed within seconds from opening the console. I guess the solution for this problem would be to disable the command outputs in the console, but I checked out a lot of forums and sites with no result.
The server runs Spigot 1.11.2 on 1GB of RAM if anyone needs that information.

Also, the console.log in the servers root folder most of the times reaches about 12GB a day, so this would be a solution too.

Answer (score 1):

You can silence command block output to the console in `spigot.yml` Look for the following configuration directive

```
...
commands:
    ...
    silent-commandblock-console: false
```

Change it to

```
    silent-commandblock-console: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Spigot, but in **Vanilla** there is a gamerule you can turn off via in-game commands.

```
/gamerule logAdminCommands false
```

*I know this is possibly not what you're looking for, but it is likely going to help someone finding this question who is on a vanilla server*

Comment: This is a reasonable solution for Vanilla Minecraft with one OP. Even though the game rule is appropriately named, it bears reminding that this will stop all commands from being logged, not just command block output.